# vifm cyrillic symbols conflicts in files' names

Tags: archlinux, vifm

I've problem with cyrillic symbols appearance in files' names in vifm.
I've tried to find any information about this type of problem, but with no success.
I use Arch Linux, may be I need to install some an addition package for vifm?
Any suggestions? Thanks for all!!

Answer (score 0):

I've find an answer. It was a problem with my locale configuration, though. I use KDE, by the way and if someone have the same issue - check your locale config - system settings/regional settings/formats. Peace:)